# Quick view/preview/outline mode in Photoshop

Tags: bitmap, photoshop

I have a pretty large PSD I got from a designer that includes a lot of groups containing three overlay layers (to create a specific lighting effect). I need to duplicate these groups and and position them around. The problem is, these effects bring Photoshop to a halt. Moving a group of 30 of these groups locks up PS for minutes at a time.

So, my question is: is there a way to switch Photoshop into some sort of preview mode (akin to the Outline mode in Illustrator), with lower-quality rendering (or even layer outlines) so I can position these items around before I need to render out an export-quality image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First approach: Settings

I had these problems with photoshop too. There are some settings you can change to make it quicker. For what I can remember the problem is, that photoshop tries to live-update the small thumbnail previews in your layers palette. This is why, when moving around a large number of layers, the software gets quite busy.

In your photoshop settings (Ctrl+K) go to the performance tab. In Photoshop CC you can change the cache settings to some default values. Try using the option that says something like "Small, many layers" (my PS is in German, so I'm not sure of the exact terminology in other languages)

Additionally, try to right click in your layers palette on one of the small thumbnails next to a layer name. Choose the option „no thumbnails“ instead of small, default, large thumbnails.

This speeded up screen design documents with many layers/groups on my system (late 2009 MBP). Let me know if it helped. If some of the settings are hard to find let me know, then I google the exact terms for the English version of Photoshop)

## A second approach

Another approach (if the other settings don't speed it up enough) is to select all groups/layers you want to move around quickly, right click on one of the selected layer/group names and choose „convert to smart object“. This merges all selected layers into one layer that should be fairly easy to move around.

If you want to access the original layers, just double click on the small icon next to the layer name. This opens up the original layer stack for slicing/editing.